# docker-compose: MySQL service not running

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to create a docker-compose file combining a custom maven environment, a specific runtime environment and a mysql server runtime.
Compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.25
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbpass
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/tmp

  maven:
    build: 
      context: ./maven
      args:
        git_user: gituser
        git_pw: gitpw
    command: tail -F anything

  runtime:
    image: custom_dockerhub_image
    links:
      - "mysql:db"
      - "maven:mav"
    volumes:
      - ./:/tmp
    command: tail -F anything
```

Services are all up and running and every volume gets bound in. I want to run a specific mysql script in my mysql container to setup my database. My first manual attempt was to just use

```
docker-compose run mysql mysql --user="dbuser" --password="dbpass" < "mysql/01_schema.sql"
```

The only response I get is

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Furthermore I tried to use

```
docker-compose run mysql service mysql start && mysql --user="dbuser" --password="dbpass" < "mysql/01_schema.sql"
```

The result was

```
..
[info] MySQL Community Server 5.7.25 is started.
zsh: command not found: mysql
```

I cant get the mysql server to stay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `docker-compose exec` instead, `docker-compose run` runs the command in a new container.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Should read the doc more carefully.
Thank you !